# Set vs List when I already know items are unique

Tags: scala, list, set

I have a `List`, which I have manually populated (ie it isn't dynamically generated), containing only unique items. For context, it's a list of validation rules which I'm using to check data against as I parse request data in an API.

The List is currently only a few items long, but has the potential to grow to be fairly large. It looks something like this:

```
val list = List(rule1, rule2, rule3, .....)
```

Is there any benefit of using something like `Set`, which will ignore all duplicate items, if I already know that the contents are unique (and order doesn't matter)? Does `Set` do things faster/slower than `List`? From what I can tell, in my scenario they are basically interchangeable and I want to know if there is a distinct reason to use one over the other.

Comment: Optimizing on the speed of traversing a collection of validation rules is most probably not worth the effort. What is more important here is the semantics - does the rule order matter?

Comment: Order doesn't matter as if multiple validation rules are not met, JSON is returned to the user containing every rule they failed to meet (it doesn't just return the first rule not met).

Comment: If uniqueness isn't an issue, and you don't have any membership tests, `.contains()`, then using a `Set()` doesn't buy you anything. Traversing a `List` will be just as fast if not faster.

Comment: Still, worth having something ordered (List), this will give you a stable order of the validation error messages.

Comment: Using a set communicates clearly to future readers that the elements are unique. The readers can tell this even by looking at the type, for example when checking the variable with an IDE tool.

Comment: @AssenKolov: I don't know about Scala's set implementations, but there are sets that preserve iteration order. For example, the Guava `ImmutableSet`.

Comment: @lii That's why I say _something ordered (List)_